# How to calculate dynamic no of rows in each section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am developing iPhone app and i got stuck at one point need your help,

I have tableview with dynamic sections and dynamic no of rows in each section.

Here is my json data format: http://pastebin.com/jmsq1pxu

I have fetched all this data in my array,
now i have calculated number of sections in tableview based on `SpecGroupLabel` key:

I found section count as `10`

```
General,
Body,
Display,
Memory,
Camera,
Connectivity,
OS,
Processor,
Battery,
Sound
```

Now in each section i want to calculate no of rows.

Here in this case 1st section is `General` 2nd is `Body` 3rd is `Display` and so on upto 10th section `Sound` i want to calculate no of rows in each section ?

and finally how should i display different section and  it's row in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ?

**Please help and thanks in advance.**

Comment: where were you stuck during counting the number of items?

Comment: Why do you need to calculate the number of rows in each section - that is derived by the number of items within the data that corresponds to that section?

Comment: I want to show data like this http://i.imgur.com/0d3TqPr.png ,I am not able to calculate no of rows in section? can u please suggest some logic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain in detail

Suppose you have the following json
{

data:[
        {
            label:Fruit,
            name: Orange,
        },

```
    {   
        label:Month,
        name: June,
    },
    {   
        label:Color,
        name: Blue,
    },
    {   
        label:Color,
        name: Red,
    },
    {
        label:Fruit,
        name: Apple,    
    },
    {   
        label:Color,
        name: Pink,
    },
    {
        label:Fruit,
        name: Mango,
    },
    {   
        label:Month,
        name: May,
    },
    {   
        label:Color,
        name: White,
    },
```

]
}

And you want your table to look like

**Fruit**

Orange

Apple

Mango

**Month**

June

May

**Color**

Blue

Red

Pink

White

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
dict   =    [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSArray *jsonArray  ;// this is your data json array
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary    *dataDict    =   [jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *getLabel  =   [dataDict objectForKey:@"label"];
    if([dict objectForKey:getLabel] == NULL){
        //this label is not present in your dict, so that means its a new section.
        NSMutableArray *newArray    =   [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [newArray addObject:[dataDict objectForKey:@"name"]];
        [dict setObject:newArray forKey:getLabel];
    }else{
        // already added to the dictionary
        NSMutableArray *getArray  = [dict objectForKey:getLabel];
        [getArray addObject:[dataDict objectForKey:@"name"]];
    }
}

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return dict.count;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
 NSArray *getArray   =   [dict.allValues objectAtIndex:section];

return getArray.count;
 }

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:  (NSInteger)section{
 return 40.0;
 } 

 -(UIView*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
UIView *view    =   [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 40.0)];
UILabel *sectionLabel   =   [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 40.0)];
sectionLabel.text       =   [dict.allKeys objectAtIndex:section];
[view addSubview:sectionLabel];
return view;
}

-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell   =   [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSArray *getArray       =   [dict.allValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
cell.textLabel.text     =   [getArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

the number of the groups:

```
NSInteger _numberOfGroups = [[_array valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.SpecGroupLabel"] count];
```

the number of the items in a particular group (e.g. `"General"`):

```
NSInteger _numberOfItemsInAGroup = [[_array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDictionary * evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [[evaluatedObject valueForKey:@"SpecGroupLabel"] isEqualToString:@"General"]; // or Body, Display, Memory, Camera, Connectivity, etc...
}]] count];
```

---

*NOTE: you can read more [about KVC here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html) and [predicates here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html).*

Comment: And you probably want to memoize this (i.e. cache the results)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an array of arrays. Each array will represent a section. Within each array add your data for an individual row.

To get number of rows in a section:

```
NSInteger rows = array[section].count
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath use the indexpath

```
CustomObject *object = [array[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```